# Getting Login error in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL server 2008 and it was working fine ,but today while starting SQL server I am getting the following error :
"**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2**)"

In SQL Server Configuration Manager--> sql server services --> MS sql server and all other service status is showing as stopped(previously it was running). I have tried to make it start but  the request failed..I have checked the event log ,its showing "**The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not start due to a logon failure**" ....My SQL server is taking windows authentication and few days back I have changed the PWD ..can it b the reason..pls help.
Note: Its not remote connection..the server is My system only..

Comment: This is a perfect example of why answers that are only links can become worthless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Stuart for ur suggestions but the problem was a bit different.
I got the sloution from http://dotnet.org.za/thea/archive/2004/06/09/2069.aspx
Its working Now :-)

Comment: that link as gone dead any chance you can tell me why this happens 
i came accross this problem 
but some time ago every thing was working fine , and it suddenly stoped working .

Answer (score 0):

In server properties in security, check that server authentication is set to 
SQL SErver and Windows Authentication mode.

EDIT: I had similar error after installation of service pack, the install switched the server authentication mode to windows only.
1.Management Studio
2.Object browser should be open in the left hand pane
3.Right click on the server instance name
4.Select properties from the menu choices
5.Server Properties dialog opens
6.Select security on the left hand menu items
7.On the right, there will be server authentication, select 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode'

This should allow you to log in as sa, once running and you are in, make changes if required to Logins and Roles

Comment: Sorry not getting..can u pls explain a bit